# CSS - class should not apply within child components

Tags: css, angular

I have a Parent component which two child components. All three components use accordion-group. My styles have a class as below and I want this class to apply only to the parent component. For some reason :not is not working for me. The class gets applied to the whole page so child components also get it

Class

```
accordion-group :not(app-child){
    .panel-heading {
        height: 44px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    .panel-body {
        padding-top: 0 !important;
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
    }

    .panel-title {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

My html

```
   <accordian>
    <accordion-group>
       <div class="panel-heading"> 
          <div class="panel-title"> 
            <app-child> 
             <accordian>
              <accordion-group>
               <div class="panel-heading"> 
                <div class="panel-title"> 
                ...
                </div>
               </div>
              </accordion-group>
             </accordian>
            </app-child>
          </div>
       </div>
    </accordion-group>
   </accordian>
```

Updates with another simple example

html

```
<div class="acc"> 
   <span class="acc">span1</span><br>
   <span class="acc">span2</span>
   <div>
      <span class="acc">span3</span><br>
      <span class="acc">span4</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
div:not(div){
border:solid black;
}
```

I want only span1 and span2 to have the class applied.

Comment: in your edited example: which spans/ divs should the style target?

Comment: It should target span1 and span2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this selector will target span1 and span2

```css
.acc>:not(div) {
  border: solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="acc">
  <span class="acc">span1</span><br>
  <span class="acc">span2</span>
  <div>
    <span class="acc">span3</span><br>
    <span class="acc">span4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This example works very well but my angular component does not. I have updated the question. I want to change the accordion-group's panel-heading etc but not the child component's accordion-group

Answer (score 0):

remove the whitespace before the :not selector

```css
.acc:not(span) {
  border: solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="acc">
  <span class="acc"> Span1 </span> <br>
  <span class="acc"> Span2 </span>
</div>
```

see the difference: first snippet is without whitespace, 2nd one is with whitespace

```css
.acc :not(span) {
  border: solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="acc">
  <span class="acc"> Span1 </span> <br>
  <span class="acc"> Span2 </span>
</div>
```

Edit: Regarding your edited example. For your example you could for example do `.acc > .acc{}` (this would only select children with the class acc of parents with the class acc)

Just look into what CSS selectors there are, you can then basically just string them together to get whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks. I tried by removing space but no effect. Is this because I am using element instead of a class? Also my class is included in styles instead of component’s scss file